# Why does the following code produce a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, unix, segmentation-fault, strtok

I'm trying to execute a UNIX command via my program that will handle up to 4 arguments, why does this either produce a seg fault or other errors?

```
using namespace std;

int main() {

char buffer[255];
cin >> buffer;


char* firstPtr;
char* secondPtr;
char* thirdPtr;
char* fourthPtr;

firstPtr = strtok(buffer, " ");
secondPtr = strtok(NULL, " ");
thirdPtr = strtok(NULL, " ");
fourthPtr = strtok(NULL, " ");


execlp(firstPtr, secondPtr);


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you're invoking undefined behavior?  (or did you already know that) ? `cin >> buffer` is breaking on whitespace, so tokenizing this on `" "` is moot. therefore `secondPtr` is NULL and you walk happily into UB-land.

Comment: "or other errors?" Which other errors?

Comment: when I exec ls the error I get is NULL passed to argv[0]

Comment: In case you're not seeing a pattern in the code below, [std::istream::getline()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crash is because your `buffer` overflows.

Try to use `std::cin.getline(buffer, sizeof(buffer))` instead of `std::cin >> buffer`
Also note that `strtok` may return `NULL`, so be sure you handle it.

Comment: His buffer is 255 characters, and this will fault with `./prog a b`.

Comment: @WhozCraig I tried it oon my computer and crash only occurs if the buffers overflows.

Comment: Ask yourself "What does `buffer` have when the input is typed *exactly* as `a b` ?" The answer to that question is related to this one: "What causes a string extraction from a `std::istream&` to *stop* ?? Among other things, *whitespace*. so `" b"` is still in the stream, and `buffer` holds only `"a"`. Now send that to `strtok()`. The rest is hopefully obvious.

Comment: @WhozCraig `./prog a b` as you typed, a, b are arguments, not standard input, that is he reading from

Comment: You're absolutely correct. `./prog`, *then* enter `"a b"` at the prompt. Thanks for catching that. Still, no buffer overflow required. (ironically he could just run the program and actually enter "./prog a b" as the prompt-input and the same problem would still happen, in an odd twist of fate).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use

```
char buffer[255];
cin.getline(buffer, 255);
```

Otherwise your second, third and fourth pointer will be empty.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/execlp/) of `execlp`, you will notice that the first argument (the second parameter to the method, the `arg0` parameter) is mandatory, *in addition to any other parameters* you might pass to the function via variadic parameters - and it is also mentioned in the text that

> The list of arguments must be terminated by a NULL pointer.

The first argument (secondPtr in your case) should be the name of the executable; so you're  violating the convention by passing in NULL here (because of the `cin >>` others have pointed out already).

But in addition, you're also missing at least one more argument at the end which needs to be `NULL`.

So, a study of man pages is highly recommended!